# What am I missing in this activity that could be causing a memory leak/OOM error?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Here's what it looks like. I'm hoping a visual will help you help me!

[image]

I have tested it on three devices and four emulators with various screen sizes (so different image sizes) and versions of Android, and I haven't gotten any out of memory errors. I let my 3-year-old repeatedly pound on the animals and flip through them like crazy and still no OOM.

According to [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) there are close to 200 installations since September 3rd 2013. I've only gotten one report of an OOM error so far, but now I'm worried that they are going to start rolling in. I'm including the whole activity in case one of my overridden methods has relevant information or something like that. This is my first published app so please excuse any newbie mistakes and feel free to criticize anything (as long as you include some suggestions for correcting it!)

setImages method from Game2Show (includes line 235, 'int currentAnimalImage...'):

```
private void setImages() {
    //Get current letter and switch in name, letter and image that corresponds.
    getLetter();
    String l_img = "letter_" + currentLetter;
    String a_img = "animal_" + currentLetter;
    String n_img = "name_" + currentLetter;

    int currentLetterImage = getResources().getIdentifier(l_img, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    ImageView l_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.current_letter);
    l_iv.setImageResource(currentLetterImage);

    int currentAnimalImage = getResources().getIdentifier(a_img, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    ImageView a_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animal_image);
    a_iv.setImageResource(currentAnimalImage);

    int currentAnimalName = getResources().getIdentifier(n_img, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    ImageView n_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animal_name);
    n_iv.setImageResource(currentAnimalName);
    Log.v(TAG, "voice: " + voice);
    Log.v(TAG, "Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1: " + Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1);
    Log.v(TAG, "Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2: " + Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2);
    Log.v(TAG, "currentIndex: " + currentIndex);

    if (Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex] !=0){
        if (voice == 1) {
            Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex]);
        }
    }
    else {
    }
        if (Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex] !=0){
            if (voice == 2) {
                Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        System.gc();
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
at com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Show.setImages(Game2Show.java:235)
at com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Show.onCreate(Game2Show.java:57)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Game2Show:

```
package com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Game2Show extends Activity {
    private TextView textViewa;
    private ImageView homeClicked;
    int voice;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent i;
    int currentIndex = 1;
    String currentLetter;
    ArrayList<Integer> alphabetNums;
    String TAG = "Game2Show: ";

    //private final String TAG = "Game2Show: ";
    private int minAlphaRange = 1;
    private int maxAlphaRange = 26;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game2_show);
        i = new Intent(Game2Show.this, MyMusicService.class);
        getMyViews();
        setupPrefs();
        Config.getPrefs(this);
        musicToggleCheck();
        userPreferences();
        setFont();
        setupAlphabetArray();
        setImages();
        Toast.makeText(Game2Show.this,
                       "Touch the letters, animals and words to hear audio.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
        Preferences.class);
        startActivity(settingsActivity);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameSelector.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void returnHome(View view) {
        homeClicked.setImageResource(R.drawable.homebuttonclicked);
        if (Config.soundArray[0] !=0){Sound(Config.soundArray[0]);}
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameSelector.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void musicToggleCheck() {
        ImageButton musicToggleButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.music_toggle);
        if (isMyServiceRunning()) {
            musicToggleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_toggle);
        }
        else {
            musicToggleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_toggle_off);
        }
    }

    private void getMyViews() {
        TextView textViewa = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.childs_name);
        this.textViewa = textViewa;
        final ImageView homeClicked = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
        this.homeClicked = homeClicked;
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/pen.ttf");
        textViewa.setTypeface(t);
         int[] color = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE};
         float[] position = {0, 1};
         TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.MIRROR; // Or TileMode.REPEAT;
         LinearGradient lin_grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 50,color,position, tile_mode);
         Shader shader_gradient = lin_grad;
         textViewa.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient);
    }

    private void userPreferences() {
        //Store childs name
        textViewa.setText(Config.childsNameString);

        //Set voice choice
        int getVoiceChoice = Integer.parseInt(Config.storeVoiceChoice);

        if (getVoiceChoice == 1) {
            int voice = 1;    //Mom
            this.voice = voice;
        }
        else {
            int voice = 2;    //yg
            this.voice = voice;
        }
        //Log.v(TAG, "voice: " + voice);
    }

    private void setupAlphabetArray() {
        alphabetNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(maxAlphaRange);
        for(currentIndex = minAlphaRange; currentIndex <= maxAlphaRange; currentIndex++) {
            alphabetNums.add(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    private void getLetter(){
        if (currentIndex < minAlphaRange)
            currentIndex = maxAlphaRange;
        if (currentIndex > maxAlphaRange)
            currentIndex = minAlphaRange;

        if (currentIndex == 1) currentLetter = "a";
        if (currentIndex == 2) currentLetter = "b";
        if (currentIndex == 3) currentLetter = "c";
        if (currentIndex == 4) currentLetter = "d";
        if (currentIndex == 5) currentLetter = "e";
        if (currentIndex == 6) currentLetter = "f";
        if (currentIndex == 7) currentLetter = "g";
        if (currentIndex == 8) currentLetter = "h";
        if (currentIndex == 9) currentLetter = "i";
        if (currentIndex == 10) currentLetter = "j";
        if (currentIndex == 11) currentLetter = "k";
        if (currentIndex == 12) currentLetter = "l";
        if (currentIndex == 13) currentLetter = "m";
        if (currentIndex == 14) currentLetter = "n";
        if (currentIndex == 15) currentLetter = "o";
        if (currentIndex == 16) currentLetter = "p";
        if (currentIndex == 17) currentLetter = "q";
        if (currentIndex == 18) currentLetter = "r";
        if (currentIndex == 19) currentLetter = "s";
        if (currentIndex == 20) currentLetter = "t";
        if (currentIndex == 21) currentLetter = "u";
        if (currentIndex == 22) currentLetter = "v";
        if (currentIndex == 23) currentLetter = "w";
        if (currentIndex == 24) currentLetter = "x";
        if (currentIndex == 25) currentLetter = "y";
        if (currentIndex == 26) currentLetter = "z";
    }

    public void goBack(View view) {
        if (Config.soundArray[0] !=0){
            Sound(Config.soundArray[0]);
        }
        currentIndex--;
        setImages();
    }

    public void goForward(View view) {
        if (Config.soundArray[0] !=0){
            Sound(Config.soundArray[0]);
        }
        currentIndex++;
        setImages();
    }

    public void sayLetter(View view) {
        if (voice == 1) {
            if (Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex] !=0){
                Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
        if (voice == 2) {
            if (Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex] !=0){
                Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void sayAnimal(View v) {
        if (voice == 1) {
            if (Config.animalNamesArray_voice1[currentIndex] !=0){
                Sound(Config.animalNamesArray_voice1[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
        if (voice == 2) {
            if (Config.animalNamesArray_voice2[currentIndex] !=0){
                Sound(Config.animalNamesArray_voice2[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void animalNoise(View v) {
        if (Config.animalSoundsArray[currentIndex] !=0){
            Sound(Config.animalSoundsArray[currentIndex]);
        }
    }

    public void sideLetterClicked(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.side_letter_1)
            currentIndex=1;

        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_2) currentIndex=2;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_3) currentIndex=3;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_4) currentIndex=4;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_5) currentIndex=5;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_6) currentIndex=6;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_7) currentIndex=7;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_8) currentIndex=8;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_9) currentIndex=9;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_10) currentIndex=10;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_11) currentIndex=11;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_12) currentIndex=12;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_13) currentIndex=13;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_14) currentIndex=14;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_15) currentIndex=15;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_16) currentIndex=16;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_17) currentIndex=17;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_18) currentIndex=18;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_19) currentIndex=19;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_20) currentIndex=20;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_21) currentIndex=21;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_22) currentIndex=22;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_23) currentIndex=23;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_24) currentIndex=24;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_25) currentIndex=25;
        else if (id == R.id.side_letter_26) currentIndex=26;

        else {
        }
        setImages();
    }

    private void setImages() {
        //Get current letter and switch in name, letter and image that corresponds.
        getLetter();
        String l_img = "letter_" + currentLetter;
        String a_img = "animal_" + currentLetter;
        String n_img = "name_" + currentLetter;

        int currentLetterImage = getResources().getIdentifier(l_img, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        ImageView l_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.current_letter);
        l_iv.setImageResource(currentLetterImage);

        int currentAnimalImage = getResources().getIdentifier(a_img, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        ImageView a_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animal_image);
        a_iv.setImageResource(currentAnimalImage);

        int currentAnimalName = getResources().getIdentifier(n_img, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        ImageView n_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animal_name);
        n_iv.setImageResource(currentAnimalName);
        Log.v(TAG, "voice: " + voice);
        Log.v(TAG, "Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1: " + Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1);
        Log.v(TAG, "Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2: " + Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2);
        Log.v(TAG, "currentIndex: " + currentIndex);

        if (Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex] !=0){
            if (voice == 1) {
                Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
        else {
        }

        if (Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex] !=0){
            if (voice == 2) {
                Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        System.gc();
    }

    //new
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Implemented to force music to stop when home is pressed.
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                if(isMyServiceRunning()){
                    stopService(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void setupPrefs() {
        ImageButton settingsClicked = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prefButton));
        settingsClicked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView settingsClicked = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prefButton));
                settingsClicked.setImageResource(R.drawable.settings_button_clicked);
                MediaPlayer buttonClicked = MediaPlayer.create(Game2Show.this, R.raw.click);
                buttonClicked.start();

                Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                                     Preferences.class);
                startActivity(settingsActivity);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (MyMusicService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void musicToggle(View v) {
        final ImageButton musicToggleButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.music_toggle);
        if ((!isMyServiceRunning())) {
            startService(i);
            Toast.makeText(Game2Show.this, "Music on.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            musicToggleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_toggle);
        }
        else {
            stopService(i);
            Toast.makeText(Game2Show.this, "Music off.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            musicToggleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_toggle_off);
        }
    }

    public void Sound(int s){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Config.spool.play(s, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume called.");
        super.onResume();
        if (Config.spool != null) {
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One possibility is you are leaking the Activity itself which can result in a lot of memory being lost.  Try changing the orientation of your screen from landscape to portrait repeatedly to see if that can trigger the problem.

Comment: Another possibility: you are loading a lot of images and sounds.   Have you tried reducing the size of these resources?  For example switching from png to jpeg and reducing the image quality slightly can produce a dramatic reduction in the size of the image.

Comment: Many Android devices, especially older ones, have smaller heaps than later devices.  Your memory allocation is mostly on the heap and as Dale has said, you are using a lot of resources.  You might consider limiting your target devices to ICS and later and therefore, in general, limit to more recent devices.  That said, the advice above is solid.

Comment: Have you tried running a memory analyzer on the application to check for any objects being kept in memory that should have been disposed? http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: Hi Dale, I have screenOrientation in the manifest set to portrait throughout the app so I removed that for a test run and flipped the device a good 30 times. No oom errors and (after the first 5-7 flips) the dalvikvm stays constant in the logcat as it normally does when I flip through the animals

Comment: Simon - I'd considered that but about half of the downloads are coming from version 2.3 and I'd hate to lose users for that version when I've only gotten one oom report.

Comment: @ThatCodeCameOutofNowhere I watched and followed this hour long video: http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/ used the memory analyzer and couldn't find any leaks.

Comment: How much memory does your app use normally? You may want to double check that your settings activity isn't doing anything strange as well. It shouldn't but I believe they suggest not using getBaseContext instead of this.